# Is it possible to set one of the default properties of getstream to the Time in ForeignIdTime?

Tags: getstream-io

Does anyone know if there is a way to set the "published_time" in this picture to the time parameter of the activity itself?

[image: [![Getstream ranking method example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWFqV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWFqV.png)]

This is the error that I'm getting ->

[image: This is the issue that I get]

What I'm trying to do here, is to be able to reset the "time" of an activity so it will show up again on top anytime we want. So in this case, by setting the published_time to a new published_time, the decay function will give a result as if it is a new activity, without creating a new activity and losing reactions.

but I also want to set this in the defaults section because, currently my activities don't have the published_time, and it's a feature we are adding. So if I can set the published_time to be the time in ForeignIdTime, no errors would show up and also the decay_gauss will work normally if I don't pass any published_time to an activity that doesn't need it